# Two CSS rules for ::selection text color - Why can't they be selected at the same time?

Tags: css

The code to change the `::selection` text color works fine if written in the following way:

**HTML:**

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
p::selection { // This works
  color:#ff0000;
}

p::-moz-selection { // This works
  color:#ff0000;
}
```

But, if I place the two `CSS` rules on the same line like below, it does not work:

**HTML:**

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
p::selection, p::-moz-selection { // // This does not work
  color:#ff0000;
}
```

Why is this not working? What is the rule to write two different `CSS` rules in the same line?

Comment: Read this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection

Comment: got the answer there. Willing to take your response as the accepted one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "What is the rule to write two different CSS rules in the same line?"

Usually, multiple selection like you attempted above (with the comma seperator) is fine, e.g.

```
div, p { 
  background-color:red;     
}
```

---

> "Why is this not working?"

In `::selection`'s case however, things are a little bit different.

Take a look at [**the following quote from Mozilla**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aselection#examples) as to the reasoning behind why this isn't working as we'd usually expect it to:

> "Due to the fact that the CSS parsing rules require dropping the whole
>   rule when encountering an invalid pseudo-element, two separate rules
>   must be written: `::-moz-selection`, `::selection {...}`. The rule would
>   be dropped on non-Gecko browsers as `::-moz-selection` is invalid on
>   them."

Answer (score 3):

This is because `::selection` is invalid for Gecko, and `::-moz-selection` is invalid for others. So, when you write `p::selection, p::-moz-selection`, each browser finds invalid selector and dismiss the whole rule because of the CSS parsing rules.

Comment: hmm right - '..  the CSS parsing rules require dropping the whole rule when encountering an invalid pseudo-element ..'  - from  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection